# Can Flask-WTF's IntegerField() data pass validation if it is empty?

Tags: python, flask, flask-wtforms

Flask-WTF's `IntegerField()` requires that there must be data, otherwise it won't pass validation, is there a way to make it pass validation even if it is empty?

ChatGPT's answer was to solve it by customizing the validation function, but it didn't work.

```
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from wtforms import IntegerField
from wtforms import ValidationError
from wtforms.validators import DataRequired

def optional_integer(form, field):
    if field.data is not None and str(field.data).strip() != '':
        try:
            int(field.data)
        except (TypeError, ValueError):
            raise ValidationError('Only Integer')
class Form(FlaskForm)
    Number = IntegerField('Number', validators=[DataRequired(), optional_integer])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`wtforms` offers a validator to handle this case: `Optional`.

```
from wtforms.validators import Optional

class Form(FlaskForm)
    Number = IntegerField('Number', validators=[Optional()])
```